# iperfがタイムアウトしないようにしたい

Tags: windows, iperf

iPerfでTCPのパケットを投げっぱなしにしています。
繋がったり切れたりする様子をTCPモニタに表示したいため、
通信のセッションが復旧したら通信を再開させたいです。

クライアント側

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.3  -t 86400
```

サーバ側

```
iperf -s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「繋がったり切れたり」というのは、`-t`で指定している`86400`秒を過ぎて終了した iperf を再度実行しているということでしょうか。

ということであれば、今のところ iperf に「終了したら再実行」といった機能はありませんので、bat や PowerShell で iperf が終了したら再度実行するようなものを作成するのはいかがでしょう。
指定期間(`86400`秒x10 など)が決まっているのなら、`for`文で回してもよいかもしれません。